# Defining type for module that exports functions with properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

new to typescript, I need help creating type definition for a 3rd party module that exports as a function that has additional functions as properties.

```
function myModule (options) { /* ... */ }
myModule.someMethod = function (options) { /* ... */ }
myModule.anotherMethod = function (options) { /* ... */}
module.exports = myModule;
```

So far by looking up how to define a function that has properties I have come to. But have trouble "exporting" it.

```
interface MyModuleOptions {
    someBoolean?: boolean;
}

export interface MyModule {
    (options?: MyModuleOptions): RegExp;
    someMethod(options?: MyModuleOptions): RegExp;
    anotherMethod(options?: MyModuleOptions): RegExp;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

Researched a bit more, closest I have gotten is:

```
declare module "ip-regex" {
    function ipRegex(options?: ipRegex.IpRegexOptions): RegExp;

    namespace ipRegex {
        interface IpRegexOptions {
            exact?: boolean;
        }

        function v4(options?: IpRegexOptions): RegExp;
        function v6(options?: IpRegexOptions): RegExp;
    }
    export = ipRegex;
}
```

But the DefiniteltyType linter throws:

```
Error: /path/to/DefinitelyTyped/types/myModule/index.d.ts:6:1
ERROR: 6:1   no-single-declare-module    File has only 1 module declaration — write it as an external module. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/blob/master/docs/no-single-declare-module.md
ERROR: 6:16  no-declare-current-package  Instead of declaring a module with `declare module "myModule"`, write its contents in directly in "index.d.ts". See: https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint/blob/master/docs/no-declare-current-package.md
```

Is it fixable without altering the module source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just skipping the module declaration wrap.

```
declare function ip(options?: ip.IpRegexOptions): RegExp;

declare namespace ip {
    interface IpRegexOptions {
        exact?: boolean;
    }

    function v4(options?: IpRegexOptions): RegExp;
    function v6(options?: IpRegexOptions): RegExp;
}
export = ip;
```